# How to losslessly compress a sequence of slowly-changing images into a video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, image-compression, video-compression

I have a sequence of jpeg images captured like a timelapse, with the same dimension and changing slowly in order. I want to compress the size of the whole sequence while still able to recover each individual image with their raw pixel information unchanged.

I googled and found that a possible solution is to compress it into a video, which exploits the strong temporal correlation (inter-frame redundancy) between consecutive frames, as suggested [here](https://www.quora.com/If-I-use-still-images-in-a-video-will-it-compress-to-be-a-much-smaller-file-size). I tried [ffmpeg libx264](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libx264_002c-libx264rgb) but none of the option combinations seem to preserve frame quality and compress total size at the same time (`-crf 0` keeps the quality but the size of the video is even larger than the input sequence).

So my questions is,

- What is the correct way to losslessly compress a sequence of slowly-changing images?

I can accept using softwares other than ffmpeg (as long as it is on windows or linux), doing color space conversion on raw images (if necessary). It is OK if a the compression is done without converting to videos. Thank you.

Comment: The first thing to try is simply subtracting from each image the previous image. (Except for the first image.) Then compress those losslessy. See how far that gets you.

Comment: I tried to encode the difference as suggested by Mark. For 2 adjacent 1080x720 jpegs, I can get 99% of the pixels in the difference matrix down to 20 values (symbols), but according to entropy law, I still need 2.40 bits per pixel to losslessly encode it, which leads to 1080x720x2.4/8=227kb. This is only one color channel, and the raw jpeg is only ~200kb. So I think decompressing jpg from frequency domain & lossless compress in spatial domain may not be ideal, if not impossible at all.

Comment: Not surprised. If you're starting with JPEG, then the original images have already been compromised by lossy compression. So why are you requiring lossless compression? Why not use any standard lossy video compression?

Comment: Because my initial purpose was to archive images, and video is a possible solution I looked into. And those images are weather monitoring images (growing at 2GB per day), so I want to keep them accurate by using lossless compression, and I hope to index each raw image by frame index. Now that the original images from the observatories are lossy, I think it is less harmful to further compress them. I actually tried lossy video and the compression ratio can reach 4.8 with acceptable quality, way better than any general purpose compression algorithms.